# Lambda expression from C# to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

What would this line of C# using Lambda expression be in VB.Net?

```
string s = blockRenderer.Capture(() => RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(h, userControl, viewData));
```

Something with function of - but I can't figure out exactly how...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
Dim s As String = blockRenderer.Capture(Function() RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial (h, userControl, viewData))
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this online [C# to VB.NET converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/). It doesn't always get things perfect, but it does a pretty good job all the times I've used it.

```
Dim s As String = blockRenderer.Capture(Function() RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(h, userControl, viewData))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim s As String = _
    blockRenderer.Capture( _
        Function() RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(h, userControl, viewData) _
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambda Expressions in VB.NET need to have a return value, the solution is a wrapper method.

```
Public Shared Function RenderPartialToString(ByVal userControl As String, ByVal viewData As Object, ByVal tempData As Object, ByVal controllerContext As ControllerContext) As String

        Dim h As New HtmlHelper(New ViewContext(controllerContext, New WebFormView("omg"), viewData, tempData), New ViewPage())
        Dim blockRenderer As New MvcContrib.UI.BlockRenderer(controllerContext.HttpContext)
        Dim s = blockRenderer.Capture(New Action(Function() renderPartialLambda(h, userControl, viewData)))

        Return s

End Function





Private Shared Function renderPartialLambda(ByVal html As HtmlHelper, ByVal userControl As String, ByVal viewData As Object)
                RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(html, userControl, viewData)
                Return Nothing
End Function
```